# I want to hide the checkbox and the submit button if a user enter enters anything in the input field, how?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="box">
<div><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]"></div>
<div><img src="images/image.jpeg"></div>
<div class="hide"><input type="submit"></div></div>
<div><input type="text" name="input[]"></div>  

$(document).ready(function(){ $("input[name='input[]']").on('keyup', function(event) { var len = $(this).val().length; if(len>0){ $('.hide').hide(); }else { $('.hide').show(); } }); });
```

//this block of code is generated dynamically several times, i wish to only hide the checkbox & the submit button that's very next to the input field where the user enters any value.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: i tried hiding using class name but it hides all the others too

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='input[]']").on('keyup', function(event) {
var len = $(this).val().length;
if(len>0){
$('.hide').hide();
}else {
$('.hide').show();
}
});
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$("input[name='input[]']").on("input", function() {
  $(this).closest("div").prev(".box").find("input[type='submit'], input[type='checkbox']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]"></div>
  <div><img src="images/image.jpeg"></div>
  <div class="hide"><input type="submit"></div>
</div>
<div><input type="text" name="input[]"></div>
```

Comment: @John Glad that I was able to help :)